# Calling an anonymous function within if of another function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm trying to "insert" an alerter if the username of a basic form is not filled and I have been helplessly trying to understand why the anonymous function within a submit function doesn't get called.

JIC on top of my html I have a prepared block for the alert:

```
<div id="alerter">
</div>
```

The function in question:

```
<script>
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["formz"]["username"].value;
    if (x == "") {
      (function() {
        alert("whoa");
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show');
        div.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
        div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('alertonempty').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('alerter').appendChild(div);
      })
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>

<script id="alertonempty" type="text/html">
  <strong>SMTH went wrong</strong> Seriously wrong
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</script>
```

And yes, there is a form that calls `validateForm`.
It does take the username variable and can use it (checked it also with an alert) however the anonymous function doesn't get called.

Please help me understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've created is a `auto-executing anonymous function`, and in order to make that function work properly, you need to add a second pair of parenthesis at the end :

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["formz"]["username"].value;
    if (x == "") {
      (function() {
        alert("whoa");
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('class', 'alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show');
        div.setAttribute('role', 'alert')
        div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('alertonempty').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('alerter').appendChild(div);
      })();
//-----^^^^
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, function declarations are "hoisted" (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) so it does not really matter where your function is declared - within the "if" block or at the top of the `validateForm` function - which, by the way, is the correct way of doing things "JavaScript way".

In your case, you declared the anonymous function but never actually called it. Your expression is evaluated to a new anonymous function that gets happily hoisted and is never used. Here is what you should do instead:

```
function validateForm() {
  function showAlert() {
    alert("whoa");
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'alert alert-primary alert-dismissible fade show');
    div.setAttribute('role', 'alert')
    div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('alertonempty').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('alerter').appendChild(div);
  }

  var x = document.forms["formz"]["username"].value;
  if (!x) {
      showAlert();
      return false;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can turn your function declaration into IIFE (even though it is a very bad form in this particular case):

```
(function(){....})();
```